# Result with lifetime parameter - enum with lifetime parameter applied to default T<'a> and E<'a> parameter (Rust)

Tags: generics, rust, enums, lifetime-scoping

I'm attempting to make a `Result` with a lifetime parameter, as an additional restrain on the `T` (`::Ok(T)`) and `E` (`::Err(E)`) generic parameters.

```
// enums A<'a> and B<'a> elided

pub enum Result<'a, T=A<'a>, E=B<'a>> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(E),
}
```

`unused parameter, suggestion: add PhantomData`

So it didn't work. I read that I can hack around the unused parameter error with `PhantomData`, but that seems dirty to me.

Neither did this work:

```
pub enum Result<T=A<'a>, E=B<'a>> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(E),
}
```

`undefined parameter, suggestion: add parameter before T`
`(twice)`

This suggestion throws me for a loop!

How do I put a generic `type` with a lifetime parameter, in my `enum` generic parameter default value?

Comment: It would help if you included some example code, that shows the context of what you're trying to do. Because it's not clear why using the standard `Result` is not possible, i.e. having a return type of `Result<A<'a>, B<'a>>`.

Comment: Instead of default types, you can use an alias: `type MyResult<'a> = Result<A<'a>, B<'a>>;`

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct, this type would make no sense:

Since the lifetime is only used in default parameters, what would the lifetime be in cases like this:

```rust
let foo = Result::Ok(42); // What's the lifetime in this instance?
```

?

The lifetime isn't used, this is where the error message comes from.

---

The question doesn't provide much context, but it does seem like you intend to *only use* `A<'_>` and `B<'_>` in your type. If that is the case, then you must use

```rust
pub enum Result<'a> {
    Ok(A<'a>),
    Err(B<'a>),
}
```

which is valid. However that would raise the question of why you're not using the built-in `Result` type, maybe combined with a type alias to avoid repetition: `type Result<'a> = std::result::Result<A<'a>, B<'a>>;`.
This is pretty common to do, even the standard library does it a few times:

- [`std::io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html): `type Result<T> = Result<T, Error>;`
- [`std::fmt::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/type.Result.html): `type Result = Result<(), Error>;`

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with excessively long `Result` types, and it didn't "click" that I could make module-local type aliases. I do still wonder how I could make an `enum` where the lifetimes of `T` and `E` are always the same so that I can construct the `enum` like `let e = Result<'a, A, B>` and have the variants of the `enum` become `::T<A<'a>>` and `::E<B<'a>>`, but I've since realized I have no practical need for this.